# finer/coarser relation

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

Given a set $S=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and two equivalence relations $\sim_B$ and $\sim_A$ on $S$, such that,

$\sim_A$ is defined as :
$$\sim_A=\left\{\left(1,1\right),\left(2,2\right),\left(3,3\right),\left(1,2\right),\left(2,1\right)\right\}$$

Equivalence classes of $S$ with respect to $\sim_A$ are :
$$\left[1\right]_{\sim_A}=\left\{1,2\right\}$$$$\left[2\right]_{\sim_A}=\left\{1,2\right\}$$$$\left[3\right]_{\sim_A}=\left\{3\right\}$$

$\sim_B$ is defined as :
$$\sim_B=\left\{\left(1,1\right),\left(2,2\right),\left(3,3\right),\left(1,2\right),\left(2,1\right),\left(1,3\right),\left(3,1\right),\left(2,3\right),\left(3,2\right)\right\}$$

Equivalence classes of $S$ with respect to $\sim_B$ are :

$$\left[1\right]_{\sim_B}=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$$$$\left[2\right]_{\sim_B}=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$$$$\left[3\right]_{\sim_B}=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$$

The corresponding partitions are:

$P_{\sim_A}=\left\{\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{3\right\}\right\}$

$P_{\sim_B}=\left\{\left\{1,2,3\right\}\right\}$

Here every element in $P_{\sim_A}$ is a subset of the single element in $P_{\sim_B}$ and the single element is a union of some classes in $P_{\sim_A}$

Also clearly the equivalency of every two elements contained in $S$ under ${\sim_A}$ implies their equivalency under${\sim_B}$
so I think $P_{\sim_A}$ is a refinement of $P_{\sim_B}$ or equivalently $\sim_A$ is finer than $\sim_B$.

Am I right?

Can someone gives me a better examples of finer/coarser relation?

Comment: @amrsa,yes yo are totally right about the notation (I will edit that), and is there any formula that computes the all number of coarser equivalence relations (well I think two sets should be given and then we are able to compare them(?))?

Comment: @amrsa, I've seen three definitions: I) $$\text{Given two equivalence relations  $\sim_A$ and $\sim_B$ on $S$, $\sim_A$ is finer than $\sim_A$ if for any elements $x,y∈S$, $x\color{red}{\sim_A}y$ implies $x\color{red}{\sim_B}y$}$$

II)$$\text{If every equivalence class of $\sim_A$ is a subset of some equivalence classes of $\sim_B$ or equivalently every or none equivalence class of $\sim_B$ is a superset of some equivalence classes in $\sim_A$}$$
III)$$\text{$\sim_A$ is finer than $\sim_B$, if the partition created by $\sim_A$ is a refinement of the partition created by $\sim_B$}$$

Comment: @amrsa,In my opinion all of them are equal.what do you think?

Comment: @amrsa, do you have any proof of this equivalency?

Comment: I don't have any written proof of that, but it must be straightforward. Certainly for (I)<->(II), and the equivalence with (III) follows from the link between equivalence relations and partitions. Meanwhile, I'll delete some of the earlier comments since I'm getting the "move to chat" question.